# How can I access CKEditor5's operations history?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have the following case: an application for management of articles, where each article can have a version in a different language. It all works fine, but operations history (undo/redo) gets reset every time I switch to a different language version of said article. I'm updating the content using "setData" method.

I see CKEditor documentation mentions a History class that has a "getOperations" method that should do just that, but I couldn't find an example on how to use it.
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_history-History.html#function-getOperations

Answer (score 0):

Found it out: editor.model.document.history.getOperations()